# -bash: /usr/local/bin/pod: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, bundler, macos-high-sierra

After updating to High Sierra, installing Bundler gives me the following error

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pod: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to affect all gems, [this cocoapods thread](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6898) gave me the fix:

```
gem install -n /usr/local/bin bundler
```

Answer (score 4):

Solved the same problem with:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 0):

strongly recommend to install RVM to manage your ruby versions in your mac.
https://rvm.io

Comment: I prefer chruby and ruby-install, however managing ruby versions is very important, that is true.